# Tailwind CSS - How to make responsive grid where columns don't stretch, but only take max content width?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I have made an inline grid row that looks good on bigger screens. I am using tailwind classes to make columns take only the width of their content, so that they don't stretch to take the rest of the space available in the row:

```
export const InlineGrid = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => (
    <div className="grid grid-flow-col gap-x-4 auto-cols-max">{children}</div>
);
```

I use this component like this:

```
<InlineGrid>
    <div>
        <Label size="small">Period</Label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <Label size="small">Employer</Label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <Label size="small">Position</Label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <Label size="small">Salary</Label>
    </div>
</InlineGrid>
```

How can I make this columns stack when there is not enough width of the screen for all of the columns to be in one row?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to specify for each screen size how many cols you want to show:

```
 <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-4 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-x-6 md:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 xl:gap-x-8"
>{children}</div>
```